# netsh equivalent on Linux

Tags: .net-core, netsh

I am having a .NET application which listen on WebSocket. Clients need to connect with the server using TLS 1.2 with client authentication. I have added the certificate details on that IP and Port using netsh command on windows machine. It is working fine for years. Now I want to convert this application on .NET Core and wants to run same on Linux. I successfully converted this .NET Core but not able to find the equivalent of netsh command on Linux. Syntax for netsh command that i have used on Windows is

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8000 certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6 appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF} clientcertnegotiation=enable`
```

Comment: Linux works completely different, so there is no direct equivalent. The Linux distribution you use might decide what you might have, but Stack Overflow is not for tutorials. Posts like https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/configuring-https-in-asp-net-core-across-different-platforms/ might help.